# Excel VBA - .Find method between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

**Question:**
Why is the `Range.Find` method not working when referencing a different workbook?

**Problem:**
I'm attempting to copy data between workbooks, but the `Range.Find` method is stopping with a "Run-time Error 1004". I'm using Excel 2007 on a Windows 7 machine.

**Details:**
On two workbooks, only Sheet1 is referenced or used for each workbook. I have a procedure (ztest) with the following outline:

1. Format the sheet
2. Loop through all cells in column E of workbook #1
3. Using the `Range.Find` method, find the value in column E of the workbook #2
4. Once found, set workbook #1 offset column = workbook #2 offset column

I'd like to do this with `.Find` - *not* using HLOOKUP or the like.

I've simplified the code somewhat, to narrow down what exactly is going on. This doesn't show step 4 above, but the error occurs in step 3, in the statement containing the `.Find` method:

```
Public Sub ztest2()
'set workbook titles
Const w1 As String = "05AR 20130920.xlsx"
Const w2 As String = "05AR 20130923.xlsx"
Dim cl As Variant

With Workbooks(w2).Worksheets(1)
  'format the sheet
  .Range("A1", "D1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  'loop through all cells column E of workbook #1
  For Each cl In .Range("E2", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
    'find value of current cell in column E, workbook #2
    Workbooks(w1).Worksheets(1) _
    .Range("E2", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)) _
    .Find(what:=cl.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Select
  Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Birds View: You are missing a DOT before Cells... You need to fully qualify your Cells object every where.

Comment: BTW +1 for a nicely put question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very important that you structure your code very well so that there is no difficulty in understanding it. If it is required, write extra lines of code so that even if you see the code after 6 months, you can identify what your code does. Also fully qualify your objects.

Try this (UNTESTED). I have commented the code. So if you do not understand something then post back

```
Const w1 As String = "05AR 20130920.xlsx"
Const w2 As String = "05AR 20130923.xlsx"

Sub ztest2()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim cl As Range, ws1Rng As Range, ws2Rng As Range, aCell as Range
    Dim lRowW1 As Long, lRowW2 As Long

    '~~> Define your workbook and worksheets here
    Set wb1 = Workbooks(w1)
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks(w2)
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)

    '~~> Work with First workbook to get last row and define your range
    With ws1
        lRowW1 = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set ws1Rng = .Range("E2:E" & lRowW1)
    End With

    '~~> Work with Second workbook to get last row and define your range
    With ws2
        .Range("A1", "D1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        lRowW2 = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set ws2Rng = .Range("E2:E" & lRowW2)

        For Each cl In ws2Rng
            '~~> Do the find
            Set acell = ws1Rng.Find(what:=cl.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

            '~~> Check if found or not. This is required else you will
            '~~> get an error if no match found
            If Not acell Is Nothing Then
                '
                '~~> Do what ever you want here
                '
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the good advice! Your code works as expected. I'm still not sure what's going on with my code, though. I'm redoing as you've suggested, maybe that will help narrow it down some.

Comment: `Your code works as expected.` Music to my ears :p Like I mentioned, your Cells object are not fully qualified and hence you are getting that error..

Comment: Sid, I really appreciate the help! Sorry, I should have said "Your code works _and_ is easier to follow and troubleshoot." So, an important lesson for me - make sure the code is structured. I like the "make sure it can be read 6 months later" advice, especially as I'm starting to build up my own bag of tricks to incorporate in different projects. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries :) `especially as I'm starting to build up my own bag of tricks to incorporate in different projects` More Tips? See [To ‘Err’ is Human](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/)