# How to use Find across multiple workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in Excel with VBA for applications. I am trying to obtain the cell reference of specific data in a workbook to build a do while loop based on the cell reference. I can't figure out why the reference is not loading into the variable I configured for it. I have used this method for data that exists in the same workbook, so I think it is related to the reference to the other workbook. I get the same error (Runtime 91) whether the MsgBox is before or after activating the consolidator spreadsheet. Specifically, the firstDataCell and lastDataCell variables are not loading. I tried to manipulate the code from this post, but got nowhere: [Excel VBA - .Find method between workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964935/excel-vba-find-method-between-workbooks)

Here is my (truncated) code:

```
Dim wbConsolidator As Workbook              'Variable to store this workbook
Dim wbQ1Actuals As Workbook                 'Variable to store workbook with quarter 1 actuals
Dim wsExist As Boolean                      'Variable to store if the worksheet exists in the actuals workbook t/f
Dim searchRange As Range                    'Variable to store the range to search for budget data
Dim firstDataCell As Range                  'Variable to store first data cell
Dim lastDataCell As Range                   'Variable to store the last data cell
Dim tabName As String                       'Variable to store employee's tab name
Dim notIn414 As String                      'Variable to store employees the VB could not find in 414

Set wbConsolidator = Workbooks("Consolidator.xlsm")
                                        'Store consolidation workbook into variable
Set wbQ1Actuals = Workbooks("(the spreadsheet title")
                                        'Store worbook with Q1 actuals into variable

tabName = calculated based on the employee's name. This functions correctly and the correct tab activates

    If wsExist = True Then                     'Check if wsExist is false after all loops
          wbQ1Actuals.Worksheets(tabName).Activate
          Set searchRange = Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
          Set firstDataCell = searchRange.Find("Pay Date", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                                              'Find the first row with budget percentages
          Set lastDataCell = searchRange.Find("Total:", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                                              'Find the sum row to track last row with budget percentages

Else
    notIn414 = notIn414 & lastName & "," & firstName & ":"
                                            'Write the employee's name to the error log
End If                                      'End this test
wbConsolidator.Activate                         'Activate the main spreadsheet

If lastDataCell Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "The variable is blank."
Else
      MsgBox lastDataCell.Row
End If
```

Please help me identify where my Find is failing.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't rely on `Activate`. Each `Range` call in `Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))` should be qualified with the workbook/worksheet.

Comment: Also with Find specify all the parameters to be on the safe side. I don't see why your code should error though, even though RTE91 suggests the value is not found.

Comment: Odd...removing the `.End(xlup)` from the search string fixed the issue. The code works fine in other spreadsheets that I have designed. It works in milliseconds, so I'm not too worried about that right now. I won't look a gift horse in the mouth.

BigBen, per your advice, I'll work to clear up the `activate` calls in the code. There are others that are not shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be more robust:

```
Set wbConsolidator = Workbooks("Consolidator.xlsm")
Set wbQ1Actuals = Workbooks("(the spreadsheet title")

tabName = "someUserName"

If wsExist Then                   
    With wbQ1Actuals.Worksheets(tabName)
          'all range references are fully-qualified...
          Set searchRange = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Set firstDataCell = searchRange.Find("Pay Date", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set lastDataCell = searchRange.Find("Total:", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Else
    notIn414 = notIn414 & lastName & "," & firstName & ":"
End If                                      

If lastDataCell Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "The variable is blank."
Else
      MsgBox lastDataCell.Row
End If
```